# Проблема рекомпозиции при множественном выборе в LazyColumn

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Я столкнулся с проблемой рекомпозиции при реализации множественного выбора строк в LazyColumn на Android Jetpack Compose. Рабочее решение есть - пометить класс `@Stable`, но оно только создаёт компромисс с компилятором.

Может у кого появятся идеи, как реализовать класс, чтобы аннотация `@Stable` не требовалась.

---

Исходные данные:

1. Есть класс модели из сторонеей библиотеки (Java), которые отображаются в строке LazyColumn как элементы;
2. LazyColumn должна поддерживать множественный выбор и сохранять выбранные элементы через `rememberSaveable { }`

Для реализации выбора я написал класс с функцией получения ключа объекта, а ключи уже потом могут сохраняться в `Bundle:`

```kotlin
class Selector<I, K> (
    private val selectable: SnapshotStateList<I>,
    private val keyProvider: (I) -> (K)
)
```

Полный код: [**GitHub Gist**](https://gist.github.com/h8leet/5bc4d8cbc7736c9f8401cd365a420118)

Состояния выбора элемента я сохраняю в map с ключом `keyProvider` и состоянием выбора (`State`):

```kotlin
private val _selectedStates = ArrayMap<K, WeakReference<MutableState<Boolean>>>()
val selectedState: (I) -> State<Boolean>
    get() = state@{ item ->
        val key = keyProvider(item)
        val currentState = _selectedStates[key]?.get()
        return@state if (currentState != null) {
            currentState
        } else {
            val state = mutableStateOf(_selection.containsKey(key))
            _selectedStates[key] = WeakReference(state)
            state
        }
    }
```

Состояния читаю в блоке `items` в `LazyColumn` и, в зависимости от состояния, меняю фон:

```kotlin
LazyColumn(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
    contentPadding = contentPadding,
    state = listState
) {
    items(
        items = items,
        key = { item -> item.hashCode() }
    ) { item ->
        val selectedState = selector.selectedState(item)
        val isSelected = { selectedState.value }
        /* Some code with isSelected() reading */
    }
}
```

Проблема рекомпозиции возникает при изменениях `contentPadding`. При прокрутке `TopAppBar` на `Scaffold` меняется `contentPadding` и все элементы в `LazyColumn` подвергаются рекомпозиции, т.к. map `_selectedStates` нестабильна.

**Рабочее решение:** использовать аннотацию `@Stable` на классе `Selector`, но мне кажется, что это не очень аккуратно.

**По другому:** если заменить `_selectedStates` на `SnapshotStateMap` (`mutableStateMapOf<>()`), то ненужная рекомпозиция возникает при первой загрузке элемента:

1. Загружается состояние выбора из `_selectedStates`;
2. `State` помещается в map, что приводит к изменению `_selectedStates`;
3. Из-за изменения map, compose сообщается, что может что-то поменялось в `State` и элемент в `LazyColumn` пересоздаётся.

`remember { selector.selectedState }` не помогает.

**И ещё:** если не сохранять состояния выбора, а только отдавать функцию `isSelected`, то происходит рекомпозиация каждого элемента, при изменении выбора лишь одного:

```kotlin
val isSelected: (I) -> Boolean = { item -> _selection.contains(keyProvider(item)) }
```

---

Может есть решение поинтереснее, что сохранение `State` выбранности элемента оставалось стабильным для compose, без аннотаций `@Stable` или `@Immutable`?

Тот же вопрос на английском: [**Multiple selection LazyColumn recompose issue**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77646011/multiple-selection-lazycolumn-recompose-issue)

Comment: Можно вообще обойтись без `rememberSaveable` - тупо при каждой модификации все изменения записывать в `ViewModel`, оттуда читать их как `collectAsState()` -а дальше уже дело техники.

Comment: @Barmaley, `savedInstanceState` поживучее `ViewModel` и `ViewModel` не нужно знать состояния выборки, только `selectedItems` в методах запрашиваю. И место хранения не решает проблему рекомпозиций. Основное, что решено: 1) каждый элемент имеет только своё собственное состояние `isSelected`, а не слушает весь `selection`; 2) сократился код экрана - все действия уже объявлены в классе (не надо описывать их в основной функции экрана), а в параметрах внутренних функций я просто запрашиваю `Selector`, а не отдельные лямбды; 3) переиспользование в разных списках.

Comment: Ну так если selector нестабилен, то почему вы его не используете внутри вложенного скоупа { ... }, как сами же и советуете

Comment: @vitidev, что-то не могу представить, как мне из `Selector`, можно вытащить состояние выделения для каждого элемента в блоке `items` в `LazyColumn`, не прочитав сам `Selector`. Тащить лямбдами, конечные результаты, того, что нужно от `Selector`, не хочется, очень нагруженный код выходит - много где работа с `Selector`. Я так, в целом, поизучал, думаю, что `@Stable` аннотация, в данном случае, не плохое решение. `keyProvider` с лямбды поменял на интерфейс для более строго контракта, его `@Immutable` пришлось помечать также.